# Upgraded to 13.04, mount.cifs returns "Invalid argument" -22 error

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, mount, samba, fstab

Just upgraded my Ubuntu Server to 13.04, and the existing and working fstab configuration for a cifs mount is failing with the generic -22 error (invalid argument):

```
12:38 PM wesley at wsrv cwd ~
$ sudo mount /Volumes/Storage/
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

This is the line at /etc/fstab:

```
//10.0.0.1/Storage      /Volumes/Storage        cifs    uid=1000,gid=1000,user=wesley,password=[hidden]       0       0
```

The server is an Airport Extreme, other machines connect to it fine currently.

This was working fine on 12.10.

Comment: Can you please execute the mount command with `--verbose`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Add the option sec=ntlm - this works both in a manual mount and from fstab

The fstab entry is now -

```
# Network USB Drive - ie the USB Flash Drive connected to the Modem
//192.168.0.1/USB /home/user/USB cifs sec=ntlm,uid=1000,gid=1000,guest,_netdev 0 0
```

Based with Thanks from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139090

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here...
sec option didn't help me.  I was able to temporarily access the data with:

```
smbclient //SERVER_ADDRESS -U USER%PASS
```

I was also able to ping the IP and Name successfully!!!

`mount -a returns` `Unable to find suitable address.`
`mount.cifs //SERVER /DESTINATION -o` ..... receives same error as yours.

I'll be keeping an eye on this in hopes it's solved; maybe what I've posted helps?

Good luck